# Driver not found: [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] play framework

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jdbc, playframework

It keeps throwing this error no matter what i do. I have added the dependencies, I have added the jar, I have also made required changes in application.conf. No clue what's wrong.

my application.conf:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="mysql://127.0.0.1:3306"
db.default.user=root
db.default.password="password"
```

my Build.scala

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.40"
)
// i am using mysql 5.7.17, connector/j is 5.1.40
```

my plugin.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.40"
)
```

It still keeps throwing the same error. I am using play 2.2.6!

Comment: The JDBC URL does not seem to be correct, it must start with `jdbc:` and why do you have quotes around the URL? Try this: `db.default.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306`

Comment: Without the quotes, It doesn't parse. It throws an error asking me to add the double quotes around

Comment: Can you check if they are included in your class path?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: If you updated your `build.sbt` while activator is running, for example with the driver dependency, you need to use the `reload` command for it to be recognized.

Comment: Yes, I have tried doing that, Still doesn't solve the issue @Steve !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your configuration

Add below lines to application.conf with your db details.

```
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName"
db.default.user="user"
db.default.password="password"
```

Add dependence to build.sbt

```
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.30"
```

Then do `activator run`

If it still doesnt work try

```
activator clean
activator run
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
**db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/databaseName"**
db.default.user=root
db.default.password="password"
```

Url wrong ???

Answer (score 0):

Configure MySQL database correctly with proper character encoding:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/databaseName?characterEncoding=UTF-8"

db.default.user=root

db.default.password="password"
```

Comment: It's not the URL that's the problem, it's the "Driver not found" part.

Comment: Solved it, There was a problem with the dependencies i was updating in my build.sbt. Thanks everyone!